# how to capture screen from another desktop?(CreateDesktop)

Tags: windows, winapi, screenshot, screen-capture

if one desktop isn't  the current desktop，so，windows will not draw it .then capture the screen by DC was not work.

help me!!!

Comment: This question is incomprehensible. Please edit it to clarify what you are asking, and provide more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to use the technique described in this article:

http://www.fengyuan.com/article/wmprint.html

Basically, you have to fool the applications on the other desktop to redraw their windows into a DC of your choice. I did this once - it can be made to work, but it's by no means trivial.

There are many drawbacks - e.g. don't expect to be able to show a nice Aero style composited desktop.